# Xcode Server bot build error

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-server

Trying to create a bot and getting the following error: `Build Service Error: Configured scheme ("App Name") could not be found, it may have been renamed or removed after the bot was created`

The develop branch has the project configured with the schemes inside the project file. I'm using cocoapods if that could be an issue but the pre integration script exists.

The other reason I thought of was that the project name has a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was related to incorrect Cocoapods pre trigger script. The pre trigger script should be

```
cd YOUR PROJECT FOLDER
/usr/local/bin/pod install
echo "Installing pods"
```